# Ternary operator with haml and sprites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ternary-operator

How can you do this in Haml with a ternary operator?

```
      %td
        - if list.active 
          %i.icon-ok 
        - else
          %i.icon-remove
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby 1.9

```
%td
  %i{class: list.active ? 'icon-ok' : 'icon-remove'}
```

Ruby 1.8

```
%td
  %i{:class => list.active ? 'icon-ok' : 'icon-remove'}
```